# Line step chart java android

Tags: android, graph, charts, line, step

I want to achieve step chart in android I have referred too many library but was not
flexible
Can anyone help in achieving below screenshot in java android,
Thank you in advance.

[image: Below is the sample one I want to achieve]

Comment: I'm pretty sure https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart can handle this. This is the most famous open source free graph library. Dig in to their documentation and figure out how to create your desired graph.

Comment: Besides the background (which might also work) I think it can create this graph. Using LineGraph, Both YAxis (left), YAxis (right) values and XAxis values are also possible. Good luck..

Comment: I want to achieve almost the exact same thing. Have you figured this out ?